# Memory leak mariaDB 10.3.37

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

Update: I've upgraded to 10.6, but I'm going to leave this question open for answers and future searches.

I have a VPS server on Centos 7 x64 with 8bg ram and I'm using cpanel/whm.  Recently the server auto updated MariaDB from 10.3.36 to 10.3.37, and from that point forward there is a memory leak which crashes mysql about every 6 days.  I'm grappling a bit with where to start with this problem. Will it be best to upgrade, or is there some fundamental issue with configuration that I'm missing?

[image: Memory use]

Some random bits of info..

top yields 1.3g use

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
14406 mysql     20   0 3179620   1.3g   6132 S   1.2 17.6 152:58.38 mysqld
```

Which does not match the 162MB shown by following command
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 170590208
Dictionary memory allocated 340032
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       1409
Database pages     6100
Old database pages 2255
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 6, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 5379, created 721, written 4228656
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6100, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

Suggested Query from dba.stackexchange

```
SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size
    -> + @@query_cache_size
    -> + @@innodb_buffer_pool_size
    -> + @@innodb_log_buffer_size
    -> + @@max_connections * (
    ->     @@read_buffer_size
    ->     + @@read_rnd_buffer_size
    ->     + @@sort_buffer_size
    ->     + @@join_buffer_size
    ->     + @@binlog_cache_size
    ->     + @@thread_stack
    ->     + @@tmp_table_size )
    -> ) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;
+---------------+ | MAX_MEMORY_GB |
+---------------+ |        3.0597 |
+---------------+
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/random.random.net.err
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=40000
#log=/var/log/mysql.log
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/random.random.net.err
```

Server kill log sample

```
Nov 20 07:09:18 server kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 19381 (mysqld) score 305 or sacrifice child
Nov 20 07:09:18 server kernel: Killed process 19381 (mysqld) total-vm:4802044kB, anon-rss:2439052kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Some highly used calls (node mysql2 pool calls)
last_comms is int(11)
timestamp is varchar(24)

```
const updateSession = async function (timeStamp, computerId) {
    try {
        const [result] = await dbh.promise().execute(
            `UPDATE nnn.webaxess_sessions
             SET timestamp = ?
             WHERE id = ?`, [
                timeStamp, computerId
            ]);
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        logger.log('info', 'updateSession error', error);
        return false;
    }
};

const updateStats = async function (webFolder, aerwareVersion) {
    try {
        if (aerwareVersion) {
            const [result] = await dbh.promise().execute(
                `UPDATE nnn.webaxess
                        SET aerware = ?,
                        last_comms = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
                    WHERE webfolder = ?`, [
                    aerwareVersion, webFolder
                ]);
        } else {
            const [result] = await dbh.promise().execute(
                `UPDATE nnn.webaxess
                        SET last_comms = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
                        WHERE webfolder = ?`, [
                    webFolder
                ]);
        }
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        logger.log('info', 'updateStats error', error);
        return false;
    }
};
```

some ps-aux log points

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql    29577  1.5  7.2 2715668 577652 ?      Ssl  Nov23  21:56 /usr/sbin/mariadbd
mysql    29577  1.5  7.2 2699668 580328 ?      Ssl  Nov23  22:09 /usr/sbin/mariadbd
mysql    29577  1.5  7.2 2708100 584600 ?      Ssl  Nov23  22:27 /usr/sbin/mariadbd
mysql    29577  1.5  7.3 2708232 585152 ?      Ssl  Nov23  22:34 /usr/sbin/mariadbd
mysql    29577  1.5  7.3 2708232 585416 ?      Ssl  Nov23  22:36 /usr/sbin/mariadbd
```

Comment: [MDEV-29977](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29977) is an updating blob/text memleak was fixed after 10.3.37. In [the complete changes 10.3.36 -> 10.3.37](https://github.com/mariadb/server/compare/mariadb-10.3.36..mariadb-10.3.37) (note sql/* changes) and [history](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commits/mariadb-10.3.37) if you can identify any used features who's codepath changed. Hope 10.6 is being more stable for you.

Comment: In that chart, does 100% = 8GB?  Then what is taking up 4+GB when MariaDB is crashed?

Comment: I added a log from one of the OOM kills.  100% = 8GB, so 75% would be 2GB remaining.

Comment: What are the top several lines of `top`?

Comment: For memory, clamd was using right at 16%, there were no other large users. Note that top varies, after mysql restart memory usage is normal. ps -aux before and after show similar results. Are you in doubt that mariadb actually had this memory allocated?

Comment: If nothing else changed in your upgrade I'm believing you as a leak. Are you using any of the following: partitions? replication? events? grant changes? roles? views? cte? insert..into.select..? alter table rename column? connect engine? updating tables with virtual columns? These constitute some large changes. I couldn't immediately see a leak in any of the code changes but could look closer at some areas with guidance.

Comment: @danblack I'm using views, also of course insert into and select, unless you mean something else.  The other items mentioned would not be in use by any api unless of course phpmyadmin or similar.

Comment: @danblack I added some example calls that are used quite often.  The jury is still out, but Its still looking like a leak in 10.6.

Comment: Please do a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org), and try to add details. `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` is a good way to identify the types of queries being run on you system so it would be a good  (even from 10.6 it could indicate the used paths of MariaDB). The VSZ of 10.6 isn't increasing on the small sample here so its inconclusive on 10.6 at the moment.

Comment: [bcc memleak](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/memleak_example.txt) on a large hour interval might show something if supported on Centos7. jemalloc [like this DS article](https://access.redhat.com/articles/6817071) could show info on shutdown if there's lost memory, but not uncontrolled allocation. [tcmalloc](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html) in a similar way too.

Comment: Ok, I posted a bug, hopefully they are easy on a newbie report.  https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30096